# Retrieve the selected values which are stored in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, split

With this code I'm populating a dropdownlist with checkbox for multiple selection,

```
sql = @String.Format(" SELECT p FROM `dotable`; ");
using (OdbcConnection cn =
      new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
{
  using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
  {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    using (OdbcDataAdapter sda = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
      using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
      {
        sda.Fill(dt);
        pddl.DataSource = dt;
        pddl.DataTextField = "p";
        pddl.DataValueField = "p";
        pddl.DataBind();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need compare the values stored in database with tha values of the table that populate the dropdownist.

If the value stored in database is equal to value in dropdownlist the corresponding checkbox are selected.

In dropdownlist I have :

```
Peter
Mike
Myriam
Roger
Marilyn
Barbara
```

On the database stored :

```
Mike; Marilyn;
```

I have tried this solution without success because in DropDownList the value of corresponding checkbox not selected.

```
using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
{
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.Connection.Open();
  OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  while (dr.Read())
  {
    string p = dr["p"].ToString();
    string[] w = reader["w"].ToString().Split(';');
    foreach (string x in w)
    {
      foreach (ListItem item in pddl.Items)
      {
        if (x.ToString().Trim() == p.ToString().Trim())
        {
          Response.Write(x.ToString().Trim() + " >>> " + p.ToString().Trim() + "<br />");
          item.Selected = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

**First edit**

I have tried this :

```
string[] w = reader["w"].ToString().Split(';');
foreach (string x in w)
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        string p = dr["p"].ToString();

        Response.Write("p = " + p.ToString() + "<br />");
        Response.Write("w = " + x.ToString().Trim() + "<br /><br />");

        if (x.ToString().Trim() == p.ToString().Trim())
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in pddl.Items)
            {
                Response.Write(x.ToString().Trim() + " >>> " + p.ToString().Trim() + "<br />");
                item.Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the output is:

```
p = Peter
x = Mike

p = Mike
x = Mike

p = Myriam
x = Mike

p = Roger
x = Mike

p = Marilyn
x = Mike

p = Barbara
x = Mike
```

On variable 'p' I have all values from dropdownlist.

On variable 'x' I have all values stored from database.

But on variable 'x' I have only value 'Mike' and not value 'Miryam'.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Perhaps the list in the dropdownlist would be more correctly stored in the database? This would also allow you to write a query to get the names along with an IsSelected attribute, which you could databind to your control

Comment: @NeutralHandle Thank you for reply, please see my edit in question.

Answer (score 0):

For my this code working good.

**.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="pddl" runat="server" UseSelectAllNode="false">
                <Style SelectBoxWidth="160" DropDownBoxBoxWidth="200" DropDownBoxBoxHeight="200" />
                <Items>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Peter" Value="Peter" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Mike" Value="Mike" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Myriam" Value="Myriam" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Roger" Value="Roger" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Marilyn" Value="Marilyn" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Barbara" Value="Barbara" />
                </Items>
            </asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**.cs**

```
using System;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string data = "Mike; Marilyn;";
        string[] words = data.Split(';');

        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(word.ToString().Trim()))
            {
                Response.Write("database stored value = " + word.ToString().Trim() + "<br />");
                foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in pddl.Items)
                {
                    Response.Write("DropDownCheckBoxes value = " + item.Text + "<br />");
                    if (item.Text.ToString().Trim() == word.ToString().Trim())
                    {
                        item.Selected = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]